# Undefined Index on Empty Form

Tags: foreach, undefined

This error is only on my local development system where errors are enabled and otherwise the programming works fine but how can I get rid of the error?

This snippet is part of the code that generates a form semi-dynamically from the column names and the error is coming from `addslashes($row[$val])` when an empty form is initially opened. Once the form has been populated with data, the error is gone but until then, each field gives the error at the top of the page.

```
// Build WHERE clause to prevent errors when loading page with no values
$Where = (isset($PostID)) ? "WHERE `ID`='$PostID'" : "";

// Open record for viewing
$sqlView = "SELECT * FROM $TableName $Where";
$row = DBConnect($sqlView, "Select", $siteDB);

// Attempt to eliminate Undefined Index errors
if (!is_array($row)) $row = [];

// Get array of column names from tableaddslashes($row[$val])
$FieldNames = ListColumns($TableName, $siteDB);

// Create variable variables from table column names and populate on post or from existing entry
foreach ($FieldNames as $val) :
        $$val = (isset($_POST[$val])) ?  safeData($_POST[$val]) : addslashes($row[$val]);
endforeach;
```

`$FieldNames`, in this case, contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID
    [1] => PageTitle
    [2] => MenuTitle
    [3] => PageText
    [4] => DateUpdated
    [5] => ShowPage
)
```

The actual errors are:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ID in /var/www/html/form.php on line 88    
Notice: Undefined index: PageTitle in /var/www/html/form.php on line 88
Notice: Undefined index: MenuTitle in /var/www/html/form.php on line 88
Notice: Undefined index: PageText in /var/www/html/form.php on line 88
Notice: Undefined index: DateUpdated in /var/www/html/form.php on line 88
Notice: Undefined index: ShowPage in /var/www/html/form.php on line 88
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$row` is empty array:

```
$$val = (isset($_POST[$val])) ?  safeData($_POST[$val]) 
        : (isset($row[$val]) ? addslashes($row[$val]) : '');
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew the reason for the error but not what to do about it but I also didn't know I could nest conditionals in this way. I was trying to avoid a messy *if/elseif/else* arrangement but your idea is very clean. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I want tell about use `$$val` feature. It looks like usefully for your task, but there are hidden problems - You may override variable used before this line and you don't see that has equal name as database column... good luck!

Comment: Yes, and thank you again. Careful consideration is always given to that to be sure there is no mismatch between the varables made by `$$val` and those on the page. There are a few cases where `$val` is overwitten or overridden on purpose within the `foreach` loop such as when it requires some additional processing but otherwise they always match. This code has been online for quite a while and working well but only started giving errors recently, apparently after updating PHP.